# Can any set be expressed as a union of nondecreasing nested finite sets?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

It is clear that any set $S$ can be written as a union of finite sets, e.g., $S=\bigcup_{s\in S}\{s\}$.

However, is it true that $S=\bigcup_{i\in I}S_i$ where $I$ is some directed set and $(S_i)_{i\in I}$ is a family of nondecreasing finite subsets?

Comment: Can't you just let $I$ be the set of finite subsets of $S$ ordered by inclusion?

Comment: @NoelLundström sorry I had expressed it wrongly. But you were right. That is always the case.